# jQuery: remove a specific click handler preserving others

Tags: jquery

I have a `form` with some fields, each one with some `click` events binded (not related with this feature).

I have to add another one to each field to show a modal at first click on any of them and only at first click.

I thought something like this:

```
    $('.field').on('click',function(){
        $('#modal').modal();
        $('.field').off('click');
    });
```

The idea was that after first click, the `.off()` method would remove 'click handlers' from all the `.field` elements.

It would be great if there would not exist other cited 'click handlers', because in this way I'm removing all of them.

I'd need to remove just this specific 'click handler' from **ALL** fields, preserving others, in this way, the modal window should appear only on first click on any form field, and never appear again with click on next fields.

Please, how to do?

Comment: Try $(this).off('click')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a function which removes itself from the handlers after being called

```
function showModalOnlyOnce(){
  console.log("Show modal") ;
  $('.field').off('click',showModalOnlyOnce);
}
```

And assign this using `on`

```
$('.field').on('click',showModalOnlyOnce);
```

This does not affect other `click` handlers as the snippet below demonstrates. The "Ive been clicked" message is always written, but the "Show modal" message only ever shows up once

```js
function showModalOnlyOnce(){
  console.log("Show modal") ;
  $('.field').off('click',showModalOnlyOnce);
}


$('.field').on('click',function(){
    console.log("Ive been clicked");   
});

$('.field').on('click',showModalOnlyOnce);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="field">
<input type="text" class="field">
<input type="text" class="field">
<input type="text" class="field">
```

Comment: No, as i wrote... I have to remove this from ALL fields... not just this one... otherwise I had used `.one()` method, more compact

Comment: @LucaDetomi Sorry I dont understand, doesnt your original code do exactly that (remove the click handler from all the fields)

Comment: Yes but... suppose that each fields have others click events binded, 3-4 for each form field. I want to remove only the one that shows the modal, not others (useful for others features)

Comment: @LucaDetomi I think Ive got you now, see if the update does what you want

Comment: Thanks, the Columbus egg :-)